# Install C API for TensorFlow on Ubuntu

Tags: c, api, tensorflow, installation

I'm trying to set TensorFlow C API on Ubuntu environment.Following https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c this guide.

When I arrived to this point: `sudo tar -xz libtensorflow.tar.gz -C /usr/local`

ERROR: `missing -F parameters`;

By the way, I tried another time with this procedure:

```
TF_TYPE="gpu" # Change to "gpu" for GPU support

OS="Linux" # Change to "darwin" for macOS

TARGET_DIRECTORY="/usr/local/"

curl -L "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-${TF_TYPE}-${OS}-x86_64-1.6.0.tar.gz" | sudo tar -C $TARGET_DIRECTORY -xz
```

But I got an error too: `TARGET_DIRECTORY: cmd not found`

I tried: [How to install C api for tensorflow 1.7, cuda 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49637146)

I expected C TensorFlow API to be installed but it isn't.